# Is it real for site to determinate my os and broser version if navigator options changed,

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping

I use selenium to view site.I rewrited `useragent`, `platform`, `oscpu` properties of navigator object in my firefox. Can site determinate my real os and browser version?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can use User Agent sniffing techniques to detect your browser and platform.
Usually this information are not really accurate and recently techniques as feature detection are more advisable.

So answering your question, YES you can detect OS and browser version using JavaScript on your website.

For a feature detection you can use a libraries like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs) can help you out on this task.

Other link of interest regarding User Agent sniffing:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent